# Multiple legends for the same aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` in conjunction with `geom_raster`. However, in each panel, the `z` aesthetic is on a different scale. For example,

```
##Data at end of question
ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill=z)) +
    facet_grid(type ~ var)
```

gives

[image].

However, since the average values of C and D are around 0 and 100 respectively, we lose a lot of resolution. You could also try:

```
##Change C to D to get other panel
ggplot(subset(dd, var=="C"), aes(x,y))+
    geom_raster(aes(fill=z)) + 
    facet_grid(type ~ var) + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

which gives

[image]

and

[image]

but I now have two y strips.

**Question**

1. Can I alter the first plot to give two legends for the `fill` aesthetic?
2. Or, if I do two separate graphs, can I remove the y strip on one of the plots to allow me to press them together - messing about with the theme, suggests this isn't possible.

**Data**

Data to reproduce graphs

```
dd = expand.grid(x=1:10, y=1:10)
dd = data.frame(dd, type=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=100), 
           var =rep(c("C", "D"), each=200) )
dd$z = rnorm(400, rep(c(0, 100), each=200))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this:

[image]

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(subset(dd, var=="C"), aes(x,y))+
  geom_raster(aes(fill=z)) + facet_grid(type ~ var) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0.2), "line"))
p2 <- ggplot(subset(dd, var=="D"), aes(x,y))+
  geom_raster(aes(fill=z)) + facet_grid(type ~ var) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,-0.8), "line"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) + ylab("")
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, nrow = 1))
```

also you might want to play around with `plot.margin`. And it seems that a negative answer to your first question can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/lDvsd4yJ0AE).

Comment: Thanks. Would playing about with `plot.margin` enable me to get both plots the same size? Just now the plot area of the left is smaller than the one on the right.

Comment: @csgillespie, it seems so, I edited the answer, it looks better now.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much the same solution I came up with, **but** I didn't think of shifting the panel label off the side of the screen - neat. The solution is a bit hacky, but I suspect it's the best solution. BTW, using `+ ylab(NULL)` doesn't display any y-axis label, which might make thing a bit easier. Thanks.