# How to scale the size of line and point separately in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, layer

The code is as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
d1=data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),z=runif(10,1,10))
d2=data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),z=runif(10,100,1000))
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x,y,size=z),data=d1)+
geom_line(aes(x,y,size=z),data=d2)
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

The size of points are too small so I want to change its size by `scale_size`. However, it seems both lines and points are influenced. So I wonder if there is a way to scale lines and points separately with a separate legend?

Comment: There is only one size legend. If you want to have separate legends you need to use something else for one or the other, like `linetype` or `color`.

Comment: what if for points `size=z*100`

Comment: Is it possible to create another size legend? Maybe for this simple example it can be replaced by `linetype` or `color`, but if `linetype` or `color` has been used or not suitable for the figure, then we still need to solve this problem. @MikeWise

Comment: I would think it is possible to extend `ggplot2` with the new functionality in 2.0.0 to provide a new legend, but I have perused the available documentation and it is not obvious how to do it at this time. I am afraid for now you will have to make do with workarounds. Either abuse another legend, or construct something with `geom_text`, etc and / or `grid` grobs.

Comment: In fact, I want to find a way to separate the legend between point and line, not just make the points more obvious.@mtoto

Comment: If you have another issue, post another question, don't edit the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two ways I can think of are 1) combining two legend grobs or 2) hacking another legend aesthetic.  Both of these were mentioned by @Mike Wise in the comments above.

**Approach #1:** combining 2 separate legends in the same plot using grobs.

I used code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539820/4718512) to grab the legend.  Baptiste's [arrangeGrob vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) is a useful reference.

```
library(grid); library(gridExtra)

#Function to extract legend grob
g_legend <- function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  legend
}

#Create plots
p1 <- ggplot()+  geom_point(aes(x,y,size=z),data=d1) + scale_size(name = "point")
p2 <- ggplot()+  geom_line(aes(x,y,size=z),data=d2) + scale_size(name = "line")
p3 <- ggplot()+  geom_line(aes(x,y,size=z),data=d2) + 
        geom_point(aes(x,y, size=z * 100),data=d1)  # Combined plot
legend1 <- g_legend(p1)
legend2 <- g_legend(p2)
legend.width <- sum(legend2$width)  

gplot <- grid.arrange(p3 +theme(legend.position = "none"), legend1, legend2,
             ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
             layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2 ),  
                                   c(1,3 )), 
             widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - legend.width, legend.width))
grid.draw(gplot)
```

Note for [printing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17075381/4718512): use `arrangeGrob()` instead of `grid.arrange()`.  I had to use `png; grid.draw; dev.off` to save the (arrangeGrob) plot.

[image: grob_legends]

**Approach #2:** hacking another aesthetic legend.

[MilanoR](http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=1875) has a great post on this, focusing on colour instead of size.
More SO examples: 1) [discrete colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2/17642257) and 2) [colour gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567200/multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic).

```
#Create discrete levels for point sizes (because points will be mapped to fill)
d1$z.bin <- findInterval(d1$z, c(0,2,4,6,8,10), all.inside= TRUE)  #Create bins

#Scale the points to the same size as the lines (points * 100).  
#Map points to a dummy aesthetic (fill)
#Hack the fill properties.
ggplot()+  geom_line(aes(x,y,size=z),data=d2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x,y, size=z * 100, fill = as.character(z.bin)),data=d1) +
  scale_size("line", range = c(1,5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual("points", values = rep(1, 10) , 
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                              list(colour = "black", 
                              size = sort(unique(d1$z.bin)) )))
```

[image: legend_hack]

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Another problem is that `size` will control line and point at the same time, if I set `range = c(1,3)` in **Approach #2**, so how can I control them separately? @oshun

Comment: You can't. If you want more control, use Approach 1.  If you want to use Approach 2, you are stuck with the same scale for both points and lines.  Notice that solution #2 transforms the points (range = 2 to 10) to the same scale as the lines (range 140-905) by multiplying by 100.  To change their size relative to each other, you change this scaling factor.  Try points*50 (smaller points relative to lines) or points*200 (larger points).  Reducing your scale range to `c(1,3)`, limits the transformed sizes from 1-3 which seems counterproductive.  Why not increase the range of possible sizes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob in programming, but you could try this methode. As you see, my code uses points and paths. I define a vector of the length of number of paths. My lines have the size 1. Then I add the sizes of my points at the back of that vector.

```
size_vec<-c(rep(1, length(unique(Data$Satellite))), 1.4, 4.6, 4.2, 5.5)

plot <- ggplot(data) +
geom_point(aes(x = x_cor, y = y_cor, shape=Type, size=Type)) +
geom_path(aes(x = x_cor, y = y_cor, group = Tour, size=factor(Satellite))) +
scale_size_manual(values = size_vec, guide ='none')
```