# manual scale for one geom's aesthetic exclude others

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two geoms in a **ggplot2** object that both use the size aesthetic.  How can I manually supply the size range to one geom but exclude the others?

So in the plot below I want to do `scale_size` for the `geom_point` but exclude `geom_text`'s size aesthetic.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=disp), alpha=.2) +
    geom_text(aes(label=car, size=disp)) +
    scale_size(range=c(11, 20))
```

Comment: do you need to map size in geom_text? `geom_text(aes(label=car), size=as.numeric(cut(mtcars$disp, breaks = 4)))` what do you want the figure to look like

Comment: `annotate("text",x = mtcars$mpg,y = mtcars$wt,label = mtcars$car,size = 0.01 * mtcars$disp)` also seems to generate what I think you're after, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 2 more solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35213634/4718512