# Separate sizes for points and lines in geom_pointrange from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot`'s `geom_pointrange()` function, how do I change the size of the point and the thickness of the line separately?

Example:

```
# make test data
df <- data.frame(y=10, ymin=1, ymax=20, x=1)

# store ggplot object
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(y=y, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, x=x)) 

# plot 1: big dot and thick line
p + geom_pointrange(fill='blue', color='grey', shape=21, size=5)

# plot 2: small dot and thin line (I want small dot and thick line or vice versa)
p + geom_pointrange(fill='blue', color='grey', shape=21, lwd=1, size=5)
```

Plot 1:

[image]

Plot 2:

[image]

Can I get a small dot with a thick line (or vice-versa)?

A workaround might be to plot the line and point as separate geoms using `geom_point` and `geom_errorbar`. Unfortunately, my real application involves jittering, so the point and the interval end up in different places (unless maybe I can control the jittering?).

I can find similar questions on SO ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893760/how-to-scale-the-size-of-line-and-point-separately-in-ggplot2)), but they don't directly answer this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `fatten` in combination with `size`:

```
p + geom_pointrange(fill='blue', color='grey', shape=21, fatten = 20, size = 5)
```

[image]

```
p + geom_pointrange(fill='blue', color='grey', shape=21, fatten = .5, size = 5)
```

[image]

s. `?geom_pointrange`:

> fatten
>   A multiplicative factor used to increase the size of the
>   middle bar in geom_crossbar() and the middle point in
>   geom_pointrange().

Comment: Interestingly, `fatten` seems to work in Windows but not my Unix environment. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried on a Mac, no idea what the problem could be, maybe your R and ggplot2 version need to be updated?

Comment: I receive the 'ignoring unknown aesthetics: fatten" on my Mac too...

Comment: @dmp @Derelict Have you added `fatten` outside the `aes(...)`? With `aes(..., fatten = 1)`, I get the same error message.