# Change fill color of dotplot_geom but retain fill color of boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have included reproducible code from the mtcars data set below:

```
library(ggplot2)    

ggplot(mtcars,aes(as.factor(vs),disp))+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar',position=position_dodge(width=.88),aes(fill=as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=.88),aes(fill=as.factor(am)))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',dotsize=0.25,position=position_dodge(width=.88),stackratio=1.1,aes(fill=as.factor(am),color=as.factor(am)))
```

I would like to make the dots from the dotplot grey/black, while having control over the fill colour of the boxplots.
As you can see, I need the fill colour aesthetic for both the boxplots and dotplots in order to separate the three factors on the x axis by the necessary group. Additionally, the dotplot's color aesthetic maps to the outline of the dots, while the fill aesthetic maps to the inside of the dots, so I need to use both, since I would like one seamless point. 
Using the scale_fill_manual function changes the colour of both boxplots and dots, but I need to have control over the colour of both separately.

I have found this other question on stackoverflow but I'm struggling to apply it to my case.

[How to scale the size of line and point separately in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893760/how-to-scale-the-size-of-line-and-point-separately-in-ggplot2/35213634#35213634)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `geom_dotplot` you could only map `factor(am)` to `color` and override the values at end using `scale_color_manual`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(vs), disp)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar',
               position = position_dodge(width = .88),
               aes(fill = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = .88), aes(fill = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_dotplot(
    binaxis = 'y',
    stackdir = 'center',
    dotsize = .5, # changed dotsize to .5 to better see the points
    position = position_dodge(width = .88),
    stackratio = 1.1,
    aes(color = as.factor(am)),
    fill = "grey70", 
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("black", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this is a great work-around. Sad I didn't come up with it myself (I swear I tried everything else)